# How can I fix Xcode 11.5 compile error. The compile error does not happen on earlier versions of Xcode such as 11.3.1

Tags: xcode, compilation

The compile error is as follows, line in code is unknown

:0: error: '@objc' initializer name provides names for 2 arguments, but initializer has 3 parameters (including the error parameter)

[Compile error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXhXY.png)

build log indicates this is happening in multiple files, but not showing line in file

[Compile errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cu3pt.png)

Comment: Some minimal extract of the code producing the error and allowing us to reproduce would be useful.

Comment: Were you able to fix this issue, if you fixed can you share how did you fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You're not calling setStatusBarHidden with the correct arguments.

Comment: The setStatusBarHidden log entry is a warning and not related to the error